# not able to pipe after data has been emitted from the response npm request

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-request

I am using npm request package. In this I can t able to pipe after response is emitted.
My code below

```
var fs = require('fs'),
  request = require('request');

var readStream = request({
  url: 'https://www.google.com'
});

// wait for 5 seconds, then pipe
setTimeout(function() {

  readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.js'));

}, 5000);
```

Comment: [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#streaming) example uses a callback instead of `setTimeout`. If the `setTimeout` function has no other purpose than to wait for the response, then you can use the method mentioned in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's an open issue on this:
https://github.com/request/request/issues/887